# Extract repositories section from composer.json using jq (get subtree from JSON, keeping the path intact)

Tags: json, jq

Is there a simple way to extract a sub tree from JSON, keeping the path?

I am using

```
cat composer.json | jq .repositories > /tmp/composer.json
```

But this would miss the `repositories` node it self.

How can I filter a composer.json to include only certain sub trees?

Comment: Try `jq '{repositories}' composer.json`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, post it as answer please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an object, `.repositories` fetches the content of a field called `repositories`. To wrap that content inside another object under a field named again `repositories`, create that object with such field and add the content using `{repositories: .repositories}`. As this pattern is so common, there is a shorthand for it: `{repositories}`.

```bash
jq '{repositories}' composer.json
```

To "extract" more than just one field in the same object, separate the field names with commas: `{x,y,z}`. To "extract" more than one field, each in its own object, separate the objects with commas: `{x},{y},{z}`.